# What does indexing.index_total means in elasticsearch's indices/_stats endpoint.

Tags: elasticsearch, statistics

As per my understanding indexing.index_total gives the count of total number of records indexed/reindexed. can I use it to keep a track of all the documents reindexed. So say I have 1M records and out of the 1M 500k were reindexed will the index_count show 1.5M ?

Answer (score 4):

`index_total` represents how many indexing operations were performed during elasticsearch's uptime.

So if you put 1M docs to the index and update 500k of them your `index_total` will be 1.5M because "update" will be count as indexing operation.